# How would I go about evaluating this infinite series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I having trouble evaluating:

[image]

I written down the first couple of terms and got 1+.40+1.66+.06 but now I am stuck.

Comment: Have you heard of Geometric series ($1/(\sqrt6)^n=(1/\sqrt6)^n$)?

Comment: I have not but by the looks of it would the fraction be the base below n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard geometric series. For $|x|<1$ we have:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}
\end{equation}
In this case we have $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$ (which is indeed smaller than 1 in absolute value). Hence the answer is $\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}}=\frac{1}{5}(6+\sqrt{6})$. The validity of the used formula can be seen in the following way:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\cdots)=\frac{1}{1-x}\left((1+x+x^2+\cdots)-(x+x^2+\cdots)\right)=\frac{1}{1-x}(1+x-x+x^2-x^2+\cdots)=\frac{1}{1-x}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Geometric series

for $|a|<1$

$$\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n=\frac 1{1-a}$$

Here

$$a=\frac1{\sqrt6}$$

Comment: I'm gonna try running that through, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

We have, for $|x| < 1$:
$$\sum_{k = 0}^\infty x^k = \frac1{1 - x}.$$

Applying this to our sum, where $x = 6^{-1/2}$, we get
$$\frac1{1 - 6^{-1/2}} = \frac{\sqrt 6}{\sqrt 6 - 1} = \frac{6 + \sqrt 6}5$$

---

If you wonder where does that formula come from, here is a fast explanation.
We start from
$$\sum_{k = 0}^n x^k = \frac{1 - x^{n + 1}}{1 - x}.$$

By taking the limit for $n \to +\infty$, we get to the result above:
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{1 - x^{n + 1}}{1 - x} = \frac{1 - \lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} x^{n + 1}}{1 - x} = \frac1{1 - x},$$
since $|x| < 1$ and therefore $x^{n + 1} \longrightarrow 0$.

Comment: must be $\frac{6+\sqrt6}{5}$

Comment: @Arashium: Thanks!